# Can one group the SHA-256 outputs depending on partial inputs?

Tags: hash, sha-256

Is it possible to predict a hash key based on half key?
Let's have some example:

I have 100000000 hash results, and they are generated by either

```
sha256( "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" . md5(random()) );
```

or

```
sha256( "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" . md5(random()) );
```

So, when someone generates a new hash (based on method "aa" ou method "bb"), is there any way that I can predict if hash is more a "aa" generated type or more a "bb" one?

I have already tried some type of Bayes classification, because I know that can only be there 2 types of results. But for each result I cannot classify hashes so that I have a good Bayes training.

Is this theoretically possible?

Comment: A secure hash function, or even a not so great hash function, is not going to exhibit any of the properties you are looking for.

Comment: thks greg. so, it's not possible to predict even if i know that half of key is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" or "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" only?

Comment: I dont know the answer, but I the security properties you are up against are : confusion (change 1 bit and about 50% of the bits change) and diffusion (change 1 bit and changes will be distributed evenly, given enough input).

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. Your question was migrated here because of being not directly related to software development (the topic of Stack Overflow), and being fully on-topic here. Please register your account here, too, to be able to comment and accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat simplified, if that were possible, you would have found a vulnerability in SHA-256. The kind of attack you're talking about is called a [*preimage attack*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), ie figuring out information on the original message from the hash. There have been some attacks of that kind against [a weakened version of SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Cryptanalysis_and_validation) but no successful ones against the standard algorithm.

Of course your MD5 only adds 128 bits of entropy and your other data one (either all a or all b), but a brute force attack against 129 bits isn't what you're looking for either.